# Piezo Transducer - Constant weight increases sensitivity, why?

Tags: components, piezo

I currently have a piezoelectric transducer connected up to an Arduino in the following arrangement

[image: Arduino Board Schematic]

The piezo is normally not very sensitive, unless I tap my finger directly on the sensor, or knock reasonably loud on the desk.

However when I apply a constant weight to it (using a pair pliers for example), it becomes surprisingly sensitive, where it can detect my footsteps.

Why is this?

I found a video demonstrating this phenomenon:
https://youtu.be/pDZ9H9sHOzI?t=25

Comment: It might be because it prestresses the crystal. Does the sensitivity increase with even more weight? Or stay the same?

Comment: It does. When I increase the weight it increases sensitivity. I haven't put much weight on it as I do not want to risk cracking the crystal.

Comment: @Ben10 Do you think the lever-arm of your pliers might contribute both to the sensitivity and to the resonance frequency as compared to the frequencies generated by footsteps?

Comment: @Jonk Maybe, however I have also placed books on the sensor, and it has the same effect, so I'm not quite sure about the 'lever' effect.

Comment: @Ben10 I'm thinking about BOTH the lever effect (which you discount, perhaps) and ALSO the change in the natural resonance frequency (which you don't discuss.) Perhaps it is the latter effect that is more important. I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: @Jonk Well you're definitely more knowledgeable than me :) So it could be the lever effect.

Comment: @Ben10 I'm not trying to suggest I know more. Not at all. I'm suggesting that in your quest to answer your question, you should consider many ideas and then work on experimental methods that will allow you to separate out these possibilities and isolate them for testing and validation. You have your own 1st thought: pressure. Fine. But the tests are conflated into a mush and you can't be sure. I've added two more to consider. Work out experimental methods to isolate and test these ideas. This is how science works. Lots of ideas. But the hard work is in experimental design and implementation.

Comment: @Ben10 How might you arrange a test that isolates the ideas of pressure/stress from added mass that may change the natural resonance. Is there a way to vary the stress/pressure without changing any lever-arms or mass? Think about how you might arrange things to decide which effect (or perhaps if there is yet another unconsidered one) is more important -- more directly related to the question at hand? This is the fun part. The part that sharpens your thinking.

Comment: @Ben10 Perhaps the best and more accessible and enjoyable texts I can recommend for learning to "think about the world around you" and design ***discerning*** experimental tests about important questions is from Stillman Drake's translations of Galileo's: *"Dialogue on the Two Chief Systems of the World"* and then also *"Discourse on the Two New Sciences"*. Brilliant thinking and experimental design in abundance. Anyone can learn a great deal about how to think and how to design experiments to explore an unknown world from reading those two works.

Comment: @Jonk for the pressure, I bought a cheap clamp from the local hardware store. I wouldn't exactly know how much pressure it's exerting, but I can use the number of turns etc. And for the source, I will have a weight on a string and drop it from the same height onto the table.

Comment: @Ben10 Yes. The weight doesn't change with the added pressure. That's an idea to consider. A clamp may have a lever arm to it, though. See if you can improve the idea still further. Or, at least, work out ways to control/measure the variables at hand. There are also some beautiful ways to graph the results, pairing up different variables in all combinations, to see trends or clustering of data. Good start! (There are still more variables I can toss out. But enough is enough, I suspect.)

Comment: Have you ever pressed your ear onto a wall to hear something from the next room? The transducer is light and might be lifted by the cables. It only receives vibrations from the air, but almost none from the ground. By pressing it on the table, it received the much stronger structure-borne noise. Plus: Some mass put on it acts as inertia, so the transducer is squeezed against this mass from the vibrations from the table.

Comment: "Sounds" to me like conducted noise footstep thru the legs of the table and weight improves conduction path vs air pressure . The same effect occurs with speakers as they need a stable sounding board for lower frequencies either a solid wall or a box.  It also reminds me of my Univ days testing a new seismic amp design with the geophone on the floor pegging my display needle left and right when I flexed my knees.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That might the reason. Relating to your work with geophones, this project is seeing whether a piezoelectric transducer can collect seismic data. Possibly for seismic refraction.

Comment: what sensitivity and cutoff frequency are you looking for.  Moving magnet geophones can detect much lower levels and also lower frequencies than an accelerometer with a Charge Amp. You have a piezo mic with a 1Megohm voltage Amp that is cheap but you might be able to calibrate it with shear force and mount to a shaker table.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I'm attempting to detect the different soil layers ('soil horizons'), potentially finding depth-to-water-table, using seismic refraction, which requires geophones - but are too expensive, hence piezo transducers. I'm definitely not an expert, so I don't have any numbers in mind for sensitivity, and cutoff frequencies, but the plan is to using a hammer (or mallet) on a plate as the source. So I would think the cutoff frequency is a pretty low frequency.

Comment: From the hydrology seismic papers with recordings I read, they appear to be above 25 Hz and much higher for deeper rock structures.  A sledge hammer and steel plate should do it and a microphone clamped on another steel plate to detect the waves ought to do it, but do calibrate it with a known geophone or accelerometer